# How to get data from Redis' Hash data structure using JMeter

Tags: redis, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am QA using JMeter 5.3 with installed Redis Data Set (version 0.3).
In my tests I want to get data from Redis database, using Redis Data Set. Problem is that data are stored in the Hash data structure, but Redis Data Set doesn't support Hashes (only Lists or Sets).
My question is: is it different way to get data from Redis' Hash via JMeter or it's not possible for today? Do you know if there are any plans to add Hashes support to this plugin?
Thank you in advance for answers. Best regards.

Comment: Based on the source, it does not look possible today, can you explain what you would like to test exactly in JMeter + Redis HASH (which type of query you want to do on the HASH). We can ask the community to implement it in an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. State that it is not possible
2. Try to reach out to Redis plugin developers/maintainers via [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins) and ask to implement this functionality asap
3. Use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to read the data from Redis hash entries, it can be done relatively simple. Assuming the example given [here](https://redis.io/commands/hset)

   ```
   HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
   ```

   you can read the value in any suitable JSR223 Test Element as:

   ```
   def jedis = new redis.clients.jedis.Jedis('your_redis_host', your_redis_port)
   def value = jedis.hget('myhash', 'field1')
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

   More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)